# Cypress testing laravel app running on local windows XAMPP problem

Tags: php, laravel, testing, xampp, cypress

I am testing 3 different web apps running on my local XAMPP's appache installed on my windows 10 desktop
all 3 are PHP Laravel apps (different versions of PHP and LARAVEL)

the problem is, that the tests randomly fail on assertion errors or server 500 errors when i run them on my desktop.

when i run the tests on our linux dev web server, it all works fine. i cant use the dev web server for development of my tests, as i dont have direct access to it. i need to run the apps on my desktop.

sometimes, running php artisan config:cache and clear helps for a short time.

When i test manually, there are no server 500 errors. it all looks like cypress is simply too fast for my machine (which is 8 core i7 with m2 disk and fast ram memory)

this is happening for everyone in my team, we all run windows 10 workstations.

I suspect it has something to do with how cypress handles caching, and i was wondering on how can i adjust the behavior to make tests on windows stable.

Or should i try to install Windows subsystem for linux and run the webserver from there ? could it help ?

I have not much experience with linux, nor web server troubleshooting.

thank you!

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? If an error 500 occurs, there's usually something written to your server's error log, or to the application's log

Comment: I tried but i am not that good with webservers.. but i will try to reproduce the 500 error and catch the logs then.. main problem is the assertion failures these are 95% of the time and these are not logged in apache or xampp or ?

Comment: so yesterday i tried extensive testing, I got 404 errors mainly now.. i did try to check the logs, but in apache logs nothing happens at the time of test failures. i tried to see in php error logs but there is no file like that in my xampp..